# Getting error on running SH files downloaded by curl (As if there was a metadata preventing it from working)

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, unix, sh

I am trying to build a script/program that runs a sh file on internet without downloading it. All was working fine, with the exception that i am getting "This file/command doesnt exist" error on `gedit`, `apt`, etc. Then, I tried to modify the script to download the file and execute it after this instead of running `bash <(curl -s --max-redirs 10 $2 -L)`, but still not working. I realized that if I finalize the script, CD to the downloaded SH file path and run it using "bash + foo.sh", it is still not working. The only method I found to run it is editing the SH file using gedit, copy all the content, remove the SH file, create a new SH file, paste and run it.

What is happening? Why is it not working? I want to run a SH script on the web just with bash without downloading it (bash and curl).
Here is my script (I will send it to my github when I end):

```
#!/bin/bash

input=$*

mkdir "$HOME/.br" > /dev/null 2>&1
mkdir "$HOME/.br/cache" > /dev/null 2>&1
rm "$HOME/.br/cache/*" > /dev/null 2>&1

if [ "$input" == "" ]
then
    echo '[X] ERRO! | ERROR! | ¡ERROR!'
    echo
    echo '[PT]: Você precisa digitar um argumento. Digite "br -- help" para obter ajuda.'
    echo
    echo '[EN]: You need to type an argument. Type "br --help" to get help.'
    echo
    echo '[ES]: Debes ingresar un argumento. Escriba "br --help" para obtener ayuda.'
    exit
fi

if [ "$input" == "--ajuda" ] || [ "$input" == "--help" ] || [ "$input" == "-h" ] || [ "$input" == "--ayuda" ] || [ "$input" == "-?" ]
then
    echo '[?] AJUDA | HELP | AYUDA'
    echo
    echo '[PT]: Acesse este link para obter ajuda: '
    echo
    echo '[EN]: Go to this link for help: '
    echo
    echo '[ES]: Vaya a este link para obtener ayuda: '
    exit
fi

if [ "$1" == "-u" ] || [ "$1" == "--url" ]
then
    curl -s --max-redirs 10 $2 -L >$HOME/.br/cache/sh.sh
    chmod +x "$HOME/.br/cache/sh.sh"
    bash "$HOME/.br/cache/sh.sh" $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7 $8 $9
else
    curl -s --max-redirs 10 tiny.cc/brl_$1 -L >$HOME/.br/cache/sh.sh
    chmod +x "$HOME/.br/cache/sh.sh" $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7 $8 $9
fi
```

Also:

- PS: I know that downloading files without reading the content before is unsafe, and because of it I pretend to make a dialog that shows its content, if the user wants it.
- PS2: You can see that line: `curl -s --max-redirs 10 tiny.cc/brl_$1 -L >$HOME/.br/cache/sh.sh`. I am making a functionality that you can just short a link using tiny.cc with "brl_filename" and acess it typing "./script.sh filename" (That acess the SH file stored on 'tiny.cc/brl_filename'). It's like APT-GET, but its a SH script 'reader', and i'm using the tiny.cc as a 'database'. Imagine some website saying: "To install my app, just type `foo filename` or click in **This button** (foo://filename), and all twill be done. If you want to view what is inside the file, type `foo -v filename` or click in **This button** (foo://v:filename)!" - It's exactly it I'm trying to do, simplify the linux installing for all users, including the noobie users.

This project will be hosted on https://github.com/Felipecconde/br.

Comment: You don't show us the actual error _or_ a checkable URL, but textly files from websites **sometimes have CRLF lineendings** instead of LF, and on Unix a script with CRLF will cause many errors; depending on your editor this would often be fixed by cut&paste into a new file. Try looking _in detail_ at the downloaded file with a hex editor, hex dump, `od -c` or `cat -v`.

Comment: PS: note that 'showing' the script on a terminal does not make it safe; it is easy to create a script that looks safe when displayed but in fact is harmful. But that's offtopic for SO.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Very thanks for helping and replying me!
The output I got was on [this pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/raw/Gs1te1PN).
And also, the error i got was on [this another pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/raw/URwwPgxV).

PS. R.: I know it, but showing in terminal isn't the same thing as downloading with the browser and checking inside the file with gedit?

Comment: Yup, that's a line ending problem all right. There are lots of Q&As about converting from Windows line endings to Unix ones if you do some searching here on SO.

Comment: @Shawn Thanks for replying me!
Why is the curl using Windows endings instead of Unix? Curl was developed for Windows? How can I use curl with Unix endings (or use Bash + Curl with Unix endings)? I will be very thankfull if you told me how can I search about it here, or if you send me one of those Q&As. "How to convert Windows endings to Unix ones when I use curl on Terminal"?

Comment: It's not `curl` doing that ... the `sh.sh` was created w/ DOS line-endings. Fix the original, and the downloaded one should work, too ....

Comment: **[PROBLEM SOLVED]**

@dave_thompson_085 @Shawn
Very thanks, the bug is killed now! Very thanks for all of you!
@tink
Also, the solution was change
``bash <(curl -s --max-redirs 10 $2 -L) $3 $4 $5 $6 $7 $8 $9``
to
``bash <(curl -s --max-redirs 10 $2 -L | tr -d "\r") $3 $4 $5 $6 $7 $8 $9``
(``tr -d "\r"`` does what @shawn said [converts windows/crlf to unix/lf, as the @dave_thompson_085 said]).

Very thanks for everybody!

Can I close the topic or give the 'best answer'? How can I vote 'useful comment' on your comments? I don't know how to do it on stackoverflow.

Comment: curl was not developed 'for' Windows; it is highly portable and runs or has run on a wide variety of platforms (some of which no longer exist), see https://curl.se/docs/history.html . However the _content_ it fetches is determined by the _server_ from which you request that content, which can do whatever it chooses _or_ let its users choose as tink suggests.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 The best thing about this it that the Curl was originally made by a Brazillian. Very thanks for the information! Also, is there any method to get the curl information but without those information be determinated by the server? (Like a web browser or something like this)?

Comment: The data obtained by a web browser is also determined by the server(s) (plural because unlike curl which requests _one_ URL at a time, most webpages contain dozens or hundreds or even thousands of resources each with a separate URL), but the content _usually_ used in web browsers isn't affected by lineendings because either they are ignored (HTML and XML, CSS, JS and JSON) or they don't even exist (images, audio and video, PDF, archives like ZIP and TAR). If you use a web browser to download your shell script it will still have the same issue.